# how to allow download after newsletter subscription?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using a Plugin (boxzilla) to show a Popup with a Newsletter-subscription form, which is connected to mailchimp.

My goal is to grant **access to a file, right after entering the email adress** (and register to the newsletter).

So far I wrote a script, which should open a link (accoring to [stackoverflow-post-3749231)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery), after clicking the submit button of the newsletter-form. But this doesn't work:

**Popup**

```
<div class="newsletter_popup">
    <div class="newsletter_textbox">
    Some text

    <!-- newsletter form -->
    [mc4wp_form id="1234"]

    <!-- The Download-link -->
    <a href="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0jH18Lft7ypSmRjdWg1c082Y2M" download id="download" hidden></a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
// select the button inside the mailchimp form
jQuery('.popup-newsletter_button').click(function(){
  document.getElementById('download').click();
});
</script>
```

**LINK on Page**

```
<!-- opens the popup 'boxzilla-1' -->
<a href="#boxzilla-1" rel="nofollow">Open Box</a>
```

**FORM** ([mc4wp_form id="1234"])

```
<form id="mc4wp-form-1" class="mc4wp-form mc4wp-form-1234" method="post" data-id="1234" data-name="Newsletter Registration">
  <div class="mc4wp-form-fields">
    <div rel="text" class="popup-newsletter_email">
      <input  type="email" name="EMAIL"  required="">
    </div>
    <div rel="text" class="popup-newsletter_button">
      <input type="submit" value="Anmelden">
    </div>
</form>
```

After submit **the popup reloads** and shows some 'thank-you'-text (mailchimp plugin) I guess I have to place the script somewhere else then? It seems like, I can't access the submit button:

```
//Doesn't work either
jQuery('#mc4wp-form-1').submit(function(e) {
 document.getElementById('download').click();
}
```

What is the best practice to achieve this task in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Blog (http://kevinsandlin.com/require-email-subscribe-download/) and this Plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-download-link/) helped me out.